# Убрать каждый третий символ строки

Tags: java

Задача такая:

1. Посчитать кол-во слов в строке
2. Удалить из строки все символы "a"
3. Удалите из строки каждый третий символ

Код решает 2 условия. Это максимум до чего я дошел, но программка ругается.
Как реализовать третий пункт?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*1*/
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = in.nextLine();
    int c = a.split(" ").length;
    System.out.println("слов в строке : " + c);
    /*2*/
    String b = a.replaceAll("a", "");
    System.out.println("cтрока без a : " + b);
    /*3*/
    int i = 3;
    int j;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a);
    int d = a.split("").length;
    System.out.println(d);
    d = d + 1;
    while (i <= d) {
      StringBuffer g = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
       System.out.println(g);
       i = i + 3;
   }
}
```

Comment: "программка ругается" - это что-то расплывчатое и очень далёкое от научного. Тут ведь не детский сад. Если возникает исключение при работе программы - об этом так и нужно говорить и прикладывать stacktrace с указанием в какой именно строке происходит ошибка. Даже "`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` в строке `StringBuffer g=sb.deleteCharAt(i);`" уже было и полезно, и показало бы, что вы к этому относитесь серьёзно.

Comment: мне бы не мой код исправить,а я хотел бы узнать от пользователей,каким способом ещё можно решить 3-ье условие.Вы меня простите,конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы удаляете символы, идя от начала строки и при этом применяя индексы (3, 6, 9 и т.д.) и длину оригинальной строки к уже изменённой, у которой и длина уменьшается с каждой итерацией (что и приводит к исключению), и индексы символов, которые нужно удалить, уже другие.

Можно либо учитывать длину изменяемого `sb` и использовать соответствующие индексы:

```
for (int i = 2; i < sb.length(); i += 2)
{
    sb = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Либо идти с конца строки:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a);
int i = a.length() - a.length() % 3 - 1;
for (; i > 0; i -= 3)
{
    sb = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

В обоих случаях для исходной строки `1234567890` результатом будет `1245780`, а для `123456` - `1245`.

Длину строки можно получить с помощью метода `.length()` - нет необходимости для этого разбивать строку на массив символов.

Comment: Спасибо!) Я всё понял!)